composeCompiler inside a Gradle Plugin
I would like to configure the compiseCompiler inside my Plugin but I am unable to access it.
I tried this way:
class AndroidApplicationComposeConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.run {
            pluginManager.apply("temp.android.application")
            val extension = extensions.getByType<ApplicationExtension>()
            configureAndroidCompose(extension)
            
            composeCompiler {
              enableStrongSkippingMode = true
            }
            extensions.configure<ComposeCompilerExtension> {

            }
        }
    }
}

but both blocks are red so I am unable to set things manually in my plugin.

You need to add any dependencies your plugin needs as implementation dependencies in the plugin build's build.gradle.kts file
